# Phonegap Google Maps and whitelist rejection

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using Xcode to build an iOS app..
I'm trying to get google maps working on Phonegap 3.x but in the debug window it says:

> 2014-05-22 15:05:14.789 foo[9345:4503] ERROR whitelist
>   rejection:
>   url='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX&sensor=true'

Config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

I've tried this as well:

```
<access origin="*.googleapis.com" />
```

my-app.plist:

> ExternalHosts | (String) | *

It doesn't seem to work at all!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

In Xcode you can see the config.xml.. HOWEVER, it isn't the right config.xml.

The file to search for is here /path-to-app/platforms/ios/appname/config.xml

Just added:

```
<access origin="*" />
```

And woila!!

Hope this will help you to!